# how to sort tuple list by first element, third element, then second element?

Tags: elixir

The data is:

```
[{{0, 0, 0}, 0}, {{0, 3, 6}, 0}, {{0, 3, 9}, 0}, {{0, 4, 6}, 0}]
```

I want to transform it to as follows, How to write the sort condition?

```
[{{0, 0, 0}, 0}, {{0, 3, 6}, 0}, {{0, 4, 6}, 0}, {{0, 3, 9}, 0}]
```

My writen code is not work.

```
b = Enum.sort(
 a,
 fn {{x, y, z}, _}, {{x1, y1, z1}, _} -> x > x1 and z > z1 and y > y1 end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enum.sort_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort_by/3) is your friend.

```elixir
[{{0, 0, 0}, 0},
 {{0, 3, 6}, 0},
 {{0, 3, 9}, 0},
 {{0, 4, 6}, 0}]
|> Enum.sort_by(fn {{x, y, z}, _} -> {x, z, y} end)
#⇒ [{{0, 0, 0}, 0},
#   {{0, 3, 6}, 0},
#   {{0, 4, 6}, 0},
#   {{0, 3, 9}, 0}]
```

---

`Enum.sort/2` would be slightly slower, but it’s also usable with

```elixir
|> Enum.sort(fn
  {{x1, y1, z1}, _}, {{x2, y2, z2}, _} ->
    {x1, z1, y1} <= {x2, z2, y2}
end)
```

Tuples are compared by elements, from left to right.